# activate custom pop up after submitting form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am building a form for an app where users record the scores of a game.  If the score is tied, I want to open up a dialog box that will ask which player won.  I am able to get a test button to work but when incorporating it into a form with more state, the dialog box does not appear.

**Form:**

```
import {useState, SyntheticEvent} from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { FormNumberElement } from './form elements/FormNumberElement';
import { DialogBox } from '../DialogBox';

export const GameForm = () => {

    const {eventSlug} = useParams()
    const [winnerIsA, setWinnerIsA] = useState<null | boolean>(null)
    const [scoreA, setScoreA] = useState<number | null>(null)
    const [scoreB, setScoreB] = useState<number | null>(null)

    // const [showDialogBox, setShowDialogBox] = useState(false)
    let showDialogBox = false
    function setShowDialogBox(value: boolean){
        showDialogBox = value
    }

    // process form before submitting
    const handleClick = (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        // e.preventDefault()
        if (scoreA == null || scoreB == null){
            alert("score is required")
            return
        }
        // assign winner
        if (scoreA > scoreB){
            setWinnerIsA(true)
        }
        if (scoreA < scoreB){
            setWinnerIsA(false)
        }
        // if score is tied, show dialog box to choose a winner
        if (scoreA == scoreB && winnerIsA === null){

            setShowDialogBox(true)
            console.log('showDialogBox: ', showDialogBox)
            return
        }

        console.log('sending data to backend...')
        async function  sendData(){
            const {data} = await axios.post('api/events/create/', {
            'event_slug': eventSlug,
            'score_a': scoreA,
            'score_b': scoreB, 
            'winner_is_a': winnerIsA
        }, {withCredentials: true})}
        sendData() 
    }           
                
    return(
        <>
            {showDialogBox ? DialogBox(
                'Tied Score', 
                'Please select a winner.', 
                'Player A', 
                'Player B', 
                setWinnerIsA(true), 
                setWinnerIsA(false), 
                setShowDialogBox(false)) 
            : ''}
            
            <form>
                <h1 className='h1'>New Game</h1>
                <FormNumberElement setValue={setScoreA} elementName='score-a' labelText='Score A'/>
                <FormNumberElement setValue={setScoreB} elementName='score-b' labelText='Score B'/>
                <button className='submit-button' type='button' onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>Add Game</button>
                <button type='button' onClick={()=>setWinnerIsA(null)}>reset winner_is_a</button>
            </form>
        </>  
    )}
```

**DialogBox:**

```
export function DialogBox(
    title:string, 
    msg:string,
    textActionA: string, 
    textActionB: string, 
    actionA: void | (() => void), 
    actionB: void | (() => void),
    cancelButton?: void | (() => void)
    ){

 
    return(
      <div className='dialog-ovelay'>
        <div className='dialog'>
          <header>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
          </header>
          <div className='dialog-msg'>
            <p>{msg}</p>
          </div>
          <footer>
            <div className='controls'>
              <button className='button button-danger doAction' onClick={() => actionA?.()}>{textActionA}</button>
              <button className='button button-default cancelAction' onClick={() => actionB?.()}>{textActionB}</button>
              {cancelButton 
                ? <button className='button button-default' onClick={cancelButton}>Cancel</button>
                : ''}
            </div>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div> 
    )}
```

**FormNumberElement:**

```
import { useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

export const FormNumberElement = ({ 
    setValue,
    labelText,
    elementName,
    }:{ 
        setValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number | null>> 
        labelText: string,
        elementName: string,
    }) => {

    // keep label from covering the input when filled in
    const [className, setClassName]  = useState<string>('')

    function handleChange(entry:number) {
        setValue(entry)
        if (entry != 0) {
            setClassName('jumped')
        }else{
            setClassName('')
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='form-input'>
            <input 
                id='nameInput' 
                name={elementName}
                type='number' 
                onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.valueAsNumber)}
            />
            <label className={className} htmlFor='nameInput'>{labelText}</label>
        </div>
    )
}
```

How do I get the dialog to appear? I saw that useState is supposed to be async but when switching to something nonconstant it still does not work.

Comment: Why did you uncomment the part `const [showDialogBox, setShowDialogBox] = useState(false)`? That's the correct way to set state and using a variable won't work, as it's not tracked by React. Also make the `DialogBox` a component and not a function.

Comment: @Clarity  I was having trouble triggering the DialogBox to render and hoped it would fix it.  Changing it to back still does not let it render.  Changing it to a component did not fix the issue either.  I can set it to true, but when I console.log() in the return the value is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code:

This code:

```
let showDialogBox = false;
function setShowDialogBox(value: boolean) {
  showDialogBox = value;
}
```

Should be replaced with this:

```
const [showDialogBox, setShowDialogBox] = useState(false)
```

Otherwise the changes to `showDialogBox` won't be tracked.

The main issue, however, is this code:

```
{showDialogBox
  ? DialogBox(
      'Tied Score',
      'Please select a winner.',
      'Player A',
      'Player B',
      setWinnerIsA(true),
      setWinnerIsA(false),
      setShowDialogBox(false)
    )
  : ''}
```

You need to pass the function callbacks, but instead you invoke those function and pass their results, so when `showDialogBox` is set to `true`, it is immediately switched to `false` when you call `setShowDialogBox(false)`. Moreover, `DialogBox` should be a React component,  not a function:

```
{showDialogBox ? (
  <DialogBox
    title={'Tied Score'}
    msg={'Please select a winner.'}
    textActionA={'Player A'}
    textActionB={'Player B'}
    actionA={() => setWinnerIsA(true)}
    actionB={() => setWinnerIsA(false)}
    cancelButton={() => setShowDialogBox(false)}
  />
) : null}
```

Another thing to keep in mind is to use `===` instead of `==` especially since you use it compare against `0`.